# Unexpected character error in VS Code for a Gatsby webpage

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, gatsby

I am receiving the following error when starting the dev server:

[image: Syntax error in ... "\gatsby-browser.js" Unexpected character (unknown character: question mark in diamond). (1:0). text from code below follows, but every other character is red space and first two are unknown characters]

The code for gatsby-browser.js is

```js
import { rootWrapper } from "./root-wrapper";

export const wrapPageElement = rootWrapper;
```

and the code for root-wrapper.js is:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Layout } from "./src/components/layout";

export const rootWrapper = ({ element }) => {
    return <Layout>{element}</Layout>;
};
```

Any thoughts on what would be causing this error?  I've never seen the pink/red bars in an error on VS Code before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check character encoding of that file (bottom right corner of status bar), what does it read?

Alternatively try to change the encoding: either by clicking that status bar item or invoking `Change File Encoding` command and then `Save with Encoding`, then choose `UTF-8` (that one without BOM).

Comment: That was it.  Somehow they'd all switched to UTF-16 ?!

Comment: I think I know what caused it.  I'm using $null >> file as a Windows workaround to not having touch.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is due to an extension running within your VSCode environment?

Try disabling any extensions you have first, especially ones that relate to your project and syntax